# Android problems with READ_CALL_LOG permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android 8.1, Java

I am new to this and am making a very basic redial app and I just need to get the last number dialed. To get that number I am using the getLastOutgoingCall which requires the READ_CALL_LOG permission. I requested like this:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 100);
        }
```

Which works if I request other permissions like READ_CONTACT but for some reason the read call log just returns permission denied without even prompting for the permission. How can I correctly get this permission or is there a better way to get the last number dialed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on READ_CALL_LOG

> This is a hard restricted permission which cannot be held by an app
> until the installer on record whitelists the permission. For more
> details see PackageInstaller.SessionParams.setWhitelistedRestrictedPermissions(Set).

Sounds like your device is set to hard block that permission.

Also, your app is unlikely to be allowed on Google Play.  See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-sms-and-call-log-permissions%2Cexceptions for the restrictions on that permission.  I think you have an argument for it, but it would be up to the whims of the Google people looking at exceptions.

Comment: So I have to whitelist the permission itself? Is there an example code I can look at for this? And yeah this won’t be published on google, it’s for personal/educational purposes.

Comment: I actually haven't worked with one of these since the change that caused it, but I think you can use  adb shell appops set uid PERMISSION_NAME allow where uid is the uid of the app.  For a personal app that should be enough.  Alternatively you can make it a system app and edit the xml file as in https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist

Comment: The adb shell pm grant command may also be able to help.